# Visual Studio 2022: проекту не известно, как запустить профиль IIS Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis-express

Учусь разработке C# ASP.NET Core. При попытке запустить приложение в Visual Studio через IIS Express выходит такое сообщение: проекту не известно, как запустить профиль IIS Express. Что можно сделать? Компоненты для отладки установлены, компонент windows IIS включен. ЧТо можно попробовать сделать?

Answer (score 0):

В итоге помогло только полное удаление Visual Studio и её установка заново. Теперь всё отлично работает.